# "Carefully" vs "Cautiously"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

> **Teacher)** She ignores what I ask her through the class and often talks to other students when I'm teaching and distracts me. I have warned her several times so far, but she always overlooks my statements. 
>   **Principal)** Uh, I see Mr. Smith, but as far as I know, her parents are divorcing and she is struggling lots of family issues. 
>   **Teacher)** Oh my goodness! Really? 
>   **Principal)** Yes, and she is also a super sensitive girl. Try to treat her........................... while we can make a serious decision about her and her educational situation.

a. [carefully](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/careful) 
b. [cautiously](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/cautiously) (or "in a cautious manner")

I see no difference between these two words here in above example. Please let me know the correct choice here and the reason behind your choice.

Answer (score 2):

"Cautiously" means "with caution". A caution is a warning, so to do something cautiously involves taking care that something bad or undesirable does not happen.

"Care" does not necessarily mean the same. For example, you could decorate a cake carefully, which would imply that the work was very *precise*. The outcome of *not* doing so would be a slightly messy, or unprofessional looking cake - but there would be no bad outcome from it, and the cake would probably taste the same.

So, "carefully" *can* mean that someone is aware of the danger of *not* taking care; however it can cover a whole lot of other situations where it simply means more precise.

Comment: Thank you @Astralbee, however, please let me know that what would be your choice from among these two variants?